# table problem in latex

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a line problem in this table and I also want to improve the quality
thanks in advance

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
 
\begin{table}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|}
\hline
    élément & avantages & inconvénients & alternatives  \\ \hline
    emploi du temps & très léger/permet l'auto-apprentissage & fluctuation du nombre d'heures & minimiser les différences de charge entre les semaines  \\ \hline
    TBL & force l'étudiant à être à jour/facilite l'initiative d'intéraction entre les étudiants par le biais d'un sujet commun & les étudiants préfèrent apprendre les questions plutôt que le cours surtout s'il est difficile à digérer & améliorer et diversifier les supports de cours (à détailler ultérieurement)  \\ \hline
    ED & permet de mieux saisir les notions difficiles & hybride entre une classe normale et un TBL & élucider le plan et les objectifs au début de la séance  \\ \hline
    CM & approche classique & très statique (on perd facilement la cc)/les présentation PowerPoint sont souvent qu'un texte projeté que l'enseignant lise & utiliser d'avantage le tableau noir pour illustrer des schémas (voir la manière de construction d'une idée facilite son apprentissage)  \\ \hline
    UVT & un vrai pas vers la digitalisation/activités interactives (philo) & site ouvert tard/certains profs ne répondent pas aux questions de forum/majorité des supports sont des PDF & mieux éduquer les profs sur les options disponibles sur la plateforme \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The main problem with your setup is that the `L` column type isn't defined with reference to the `X` column type. Hence, there can be absolutely no expectation that the width of the `tabularx` environment will equal `\textwidth`.
- One way to fix this is to replace

  ```
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering
  ```
- I don't think it's a good idea to center the contents of the cells horizontally; left-alignment would seem preferable.
- LaTeX cannot perform a line break at a hard-coded `/` interword character. Replace all six instances of `/` with `\slash` .
- I'd also give the table a more open "look", by getting rid of all vertical lines and by using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.  This may be done by employing the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
%\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % I wouldn't use this
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lLLL @{}}
    \toprule
    Elément & Avantages & Inconvénients & Alternatives  \\ 
    \midrule
    emploi du temps & 
    très léger\slash permet l'auto-\hspace{0pt}apprentissage & 
    fluctuation du nombre d'heures & 
    minimiser les différences de charge entre les semaines  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    TBL & 
    force l'étudiant à être à jour\slash facilite l'initiative 
    d'intéraction entre les étudiants par le biais d'un sujet commun & 
    les étudiants préfèrent apprendre les questions plutôt que le cours 
    surtout s'il est difficile à digérer & 
    améliorer et diversifier les supports de cours (à détailler ultérieurement)  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    ED & 
    permet de mieux saisir les notions difficiles & 
    hybride entre une classe normale et un TBL & 
    élucider le plan et les objectifs au début de la séance  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    CM & 
    approche classique & 
    très statique (on perd facilement la cc)\slash les présentation 
    PowerPoint sont souvent qu'un texte projeté que l'enseignant lise & 
    utiliser d'avantage le tableau noir pour illustrer des schémas (voir 
    la manière de construction d'une idée facilite son apprentissage)  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    UVT & 
    un vrai pas vers la digitalisation\slash activités interactives (philo) & 
    site ouvert tard\slash certains profs ne répondent pas aux questions 
    de forum\slash majorité des supports sont des PDF & 
    mieux éduquer les profs sur les options disponibles sur la plateforme \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i don't know how to thank you , if you have time can you show me how to write every sentence in a line so i'll be able to delete that ugly slash

Comment: @karaaabdelaziz - I'm not sure what the `/` (`\slash`) symbol is supposed to denote in the table. If you need to generate line breaks at those points, try replacing `\slash` with `;\linebreak`.